# Generate cross-platform compatible Blowfish hash (PHP/Ruby)

Tags: php, ruby, blowfish, crypt

In PHP we are generating some password hashes using the built-in [crypt()](http://au.php.net/crypt) function to produce a blowfish hash.

```
<?php $hash = crypt("secure password", '$2a$10$ ... salt here ... $');
```

I see that ruby has [String#crypt](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-crypt), but the output we get is entirely different (much shorter hash).  Looking at the man page for `crypt (3)`, only some Linux distros add blowfish support to glibc, so I assume ruby doesn't support it.

Now I googled and found the `crypt` gem, but it seems to be hard-coded to do 2^16 cycles instead of the 2^10 we're using.  It also gives me an exception in ruby 1.9.3:

```
Crypt::Blowfish.new("abc").encrypt_block("foo")
TypeError: can't convert String into Integer
from /Users/chris/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/crypt-1.1.4/crypt/blowfish.rb:47:in `|'
```

Does anybody know how we can produce the same blowfish hashes in ruby that we have generated in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BCrypt gem does what we need:

```
BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret("bob", "$2a$10$ ... salt here ...")
```